# How do I get the dirty records from an ExtJS data store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Other than iterating over the records in the store and checking the dirty flag, is there a cleaner way?

**EDIT**

I am using ExtJS4, btw.

Here is a snippet of the data returned.  Notice there is a `dirty: true` with the `modified` object set (which is actually the OLD data and the `data` object contains the NEW data)

```
data: Ext.Class.Class.newClass
    items: Array[3]
        0: Ext.Class.Class.newClass
            data: Object
                incidentCount: 14
                incidentKey: "5466BD05-E4DD-4C1F-9F73-61ABAC6D3753"
            dirty: true
            id: "Ext.data.Store.ImplicitModel-TEDetailIncidencesStore-ext-record-13"
            index: 0
            internalId: "ext-record-13"
            modified: Object
                incidentCount: 7
```

Notice the `data` block contains an `incidentCount` of 14.  That is the **NEW** value and the `modified` block contains the **OLD** value of 7.

**EDIT 2**

I load the store with:

```
TimeEntryDetailsStore.load({
     params:{
        timeEntryKey:"myKey"
     }
});
```

After this fires, the above store is successfully loaded with 3 rows.  Then, when I change a value, the dirty flag is set and you get the above block of data

Thanks

**EDIT 3**

This is the code I am going to use unless someone has a better way.  I don't understand why the `getUpdatedRecords()` returns an empty array.  But oh well.

```
for(c=0; c < TEDetailIncidencesStore.count(); c++ ) {
    if( TEDetailIncidencesStore.data.items[c]["dirty"] == true) {
        var dirtyRecord = TEDetailIncidencesStore.data.items[c];
        updateTEDetailIncidences(dirtyRecord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post soem of your code rather than what is displayed in the console

Comment: BTW, `store.getNewRecords()` returns all three records.  Both dirty and non-dirty??

Comment: so what does `TimeEntryDetailsStore.getUpdatedRecords()` return? just an empty array. I'd really need to see the code for your grid and store to look into this further.

Comment: Yeah it returns an empty array

Comment: That's really about all the code I have.  I simply load the store on Ext.ready with some test data.  The store is bound to a `Ext.grid.Panel`.  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is that the store reader needs to designate a idProperty or all rows are considered new. Here's the construct that is working for me:

```
Ext.define('Sites', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
    {name: 'inCphr', type: 'boolean'},
    {name: 'department', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'commune', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'clinic', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'sitecode', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'dbsite', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'ipAddress', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'network', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'lastChanged', type: 'date'}
    ]
}); 
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Sites',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'getHaitiSites.php?task=get',
        reader:{ 
            type:'json',
            root: 'results',
            idProperty: 'sitecode'
        }
    }
});
```

If you can get a grid to show 'dirty' elements, then store.getUpdatedRecords().length will be > 0. I saw one comment that suggested this would only work with a json reader, but I don't see why it wouldn't work for other data structures as well.

Comment: FYI, you can also set the `idProperty` on the model to keep it all in one place. IMHO this should be part of the model definition as the idProperty shouldn't change throughout your application in various stores that may use the same model.

Answer (score 6):

`store.getUpdatedRecords()` in [ExtJs 4](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getUpdatedRecords) or `store.getModifiedRecords()` in ExtJs3

Comment: I saw that, and tried it, but it returns an empty array.  Even though the items clearly have "dirty:true" entries.  In fact, I can even see the red triangles.

Comment: Well, right now I'm just working in the console.  The datastore loads correctly.  I will update a snippet of the store data.  I am using version 4

Answer (score 3):

How about the getModifiedRecords() method on your store? That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the specified validations of model fields.

See the url below:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141421-Ext.data.Store-getNewRecords%28%29-behaves-strange